# undefined symbol: gdk_screen_get_primary_monitor

Tags: linux, chromium

```
$ chromium-browser
/usr/bin/chromium-browser: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/chromium-browser: undefined symbol: gdk_screen_get_primary_monitor
```

not able to start chromium on linux (rhel 6.2)

```
$ rpm -qa | grep chromium
chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64

$ rpm -qa | grep libX11
libX11-common-1.5.0-4.el6.noarch
libX11-1.5.0-4.el6.i686
libX11-1.5.0-4.el6.x86_64

$ rpm -qa | grep gtk2
pygtk2-libglade-2.16.0-3.el6.x86_64
gtk2-immodule-xim-2.18.9-12.el6.x86_64
pygtk2-2.16.0-3.el6.x86_64
libcanberra-gtk2-0.22-1.el6.x86_64
gtk2-engines-2.18.4-5.el6.x86_64
gtk2-2.18.9-12.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

On Gdk reference manual ( https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/2.24/GdkScreen.html#gdk-screen-get-primary-monitor ),

gdk_screen_get_primary_monitor() is available on gtk-2.20 or above, but it seems your gtk2 version is 2.18.

If you want to use chromium binary, you must upgrade your gtk or your linux distribution version.